# Unity Server not executing commands by client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity-networking

I'm working on a very simple/basic client-server networking program, the basis of a future game I hope to create. Now the client program/project DOES successfully connect with the 'server program/project' (both completely separate). However when it comes to having the client send a request/command to the server. Well it doesn't send the command to the server, it executes it on the client.

I read about changing the 'Monodevelop' inheritance to 'NetworkBehaviour' so I did and it resulting in an error along the lines of;

```
Command xxx was sent to the server
...Debug.logerror(object
```

So I seemed to have got half way there, it allegedly sent the command to the server, but the server did nothing with it. I don't know why.

Below are the relatively short programs I've got for my server and client and are pretty much the same, but if anyone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it, as my University course didn't really go into Network Programming all that much;

***Server Code***

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class server : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string IP = "127.0.0.1";
    public int port = 25001;
    public int prevConns = 0;
    private int currConns = 0;

    public virtual void OnServerReady (NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        NetworkServer.SetClientReady (conn);
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected) {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Start Client")) {
                Network.Connect (IP, port);
            }
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Start Server")) {
                Network.InitializeServer (20, port, false);
            }
        } else {
            //CLIENT - NOT NEEDED
            if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client) {
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Client");
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Disconnect")) {
                    Network.Disconnect (250);
                }
            }
            if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server) {               
                currConns = Network.connections.Length;
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Server");
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Connections: " + currConns);

                if (prevConns != currConns) {
                    if (prevConns < currConns) {
                        Debug.Log ("NEW CONNECTION");
                        prevConns++;

                    } else if (prevConns > currConns) {
                        Debug.Log ("Lost CONNECTION");
                        prevConns--;
                    }
                }

                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 15, 100, 25), "Shutdown")) {
                    Network.Disconnect (250);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

***Client Code***

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class connection : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string IP = "127.0.0.1";
    public int port = 25001;
    public GameObject player;

    public virtual void OnClientConnect (NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        ClientScene.Ready (conn);
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected) {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Start Client")) {
                Network.Connect (IP, port);
            }
        } else {
            if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client) {
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Client");
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Disconnect")) {
                    Network.Disconnect (250);
                }

                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 150, 100, 25), "Send Cmd")) {
                    CmdSendCommand ();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSendCommand ()
    {
        NetworkBehaviour.print ("HELLO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck? I am struck with same problem.